# Invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' and 'unsigned char')

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, bitwise-operators, cin, operation

want to apply OR operation between two numbers, but showing the above error , hence am unable to understand what might be the problem!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
unsigned char a,b;
cin>>a>>b;       //input two number
cout << a | b;   //applying bitwise OR operation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<<` has higher [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `|`, so by default it interprets `cout << a | b;` as though you'd written `(cout << a) | b;`. To get what you want, rewrite your expression as `cout << (a | b);`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write the expression in parentheses .
`cout << (a | b);`

Comment: Please give a brief explanation of why this is necessary.  I know it's necessary, but answers given should be informative.